# docker-compose.yml issue nodejs and mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I trying to dockerize my `nodeJS` api. Check out the following files :

**.\package.json**

```
{
  "name": "test-api",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "TBD",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "test",
    "API"
  ],
  "author": "test",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^2.0.1",
    "bcrypt-promise": "^2.0.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "debug": "^3.1.0",
    "dotenv": "^6.0.0",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.3.0",
    "morgan": "^1.9.0",
    "multer": "^1.3.1",
    "mysql2": "^1.5.3",
    "nodemailer": "^4.6.7",
    "parse-error": "^0.2.0",
    "passport": "^0.4.0",
    "passport-jwt": "^4.0.0",
    "sequelize": "^4.37.10",
    "validator": "^10.4.0"
  }
}
```

**.\docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2'
services:
  api:
    build: .
    ports:
     - "4200:4200"
    depends_on:
     - db
    environment:
     - DATABASE_HOST=db
    volumes:
     - .:/usr/src/app
     - /usr/src/app/node_modules
  db:
    build: ./db
```

**.\Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:8
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 4200
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

**.\db\Dockerfile**

```
FROM mysql:latest

ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD root  
ENV MYSQL_DATABASE test_dev  
ENV MYSQL_USER test-dev  
ENV MYSQL_PASSWORD testapi
```

I get the following error when I do "docker-compose up"-
[image: I get the following error when I do "docker-compose up"-]

I'm pretty new to this, solution to solve this and few pointers on what to research more would help me a lot!

Comment: What have you already tried?  What file do you expect to be at `/usr/src/app/package.json`, and how would it have gotten there?

Comment: @DavidMaze i've put in the code according to this https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/nodejs-docker-webapp/

WORKDIR /usr/src/app -> this will be the pwd from now on
COPY package*.json ./ -> file will be copied from ./ to pwd

Comment: I think you're copying package.json to an existing folder and after that you're mounting volume. Try removing `- .:/usr/src/app` line from compose file

Comment: @mulg0r still the same error https://imgur.com/obkKeTH

Comment: 1) How does your directory tree looks like at `./`. 2) Remove that second volume from the `api` service in docker-compose because it does not make any sense to have it since you already mounted whole directory to `/usr/src/app` 3) You don't need a Dockerfile for the `db`, use the `environment` configuration for `db` service in docker-compose file.

Comment: Build image with `docker-compose build --no-cache`. Then do `docker-compose up` to recreate the container.

Comment: @emix this is how it looks @ ./ https://i.imgur.com/9ZhFjBD.png
also i'm getting the same error when i try to build

Answer (score 0):

Try with this Dockerfile (avoid COPY *) and I recommend to use the absolute path in destination:

.\Dockerfile

```
FROM node:8
COPY package.json /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 4200
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

Comment: deleted all the images before i did "docker-compose up" and still got error https://imgur.com/obkKeTH

Comment: I need package.json to simulate exactly your case